# Как сохранить страницу через Chrome DevTool?

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

Во многих браузерах есть возможность "Сохранить страницу как..." и далее в формате в mhtml, в итоге страница сохранена одним файлом один в один как её видит пользователь, с возможностью посмотреть весь HTML код, стили, вообще всё.

Вопрос вот в чем, возможно ли так же сохранить страницу имея в распоряжении только Chrome DevTool?

По умолчанию, в контекстом меню нет вообще сохранения страницы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте `Ctrl+S`

Comment: @De.Minov, попробовал первым делом - не работает) Не исключено, что это сочетание клавиш отключено.